# Subset rows that contain some sequence of characters in one variable

Tags: r, subset

I would like to subset the rows that have a concrete sequence of characters in one variable.

For example I would like to subset the rows that have at least three consecutive 1 ("111"; e.g. "01110", "11111", "01111") in the variable history.

Here is some example data:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
history <- c("01110", "00001", "11111", "01111", "11011", "11100",
             "00001", "10101", "11011", "10111")
(df <- data.frame(id, history))
#    id history
# 1   1   01110
# 2   2   00001
# 3   3   11111
# 4   4   01111
# 5   5   11011
# 6   6   11100
# 7   7   00001
# 8   8   10101
# 9   9   11011
# 10 10   10111
```

In this case I would want to select rows 1, 3, 4, 6, and 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df[grep('1{3,}', df$history),]
```

Comment: Thanks, and if it were characters like: `id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
history <- c("01110", "00001", "11111", "01111", "11011", "11100",
             "00001", "10101", "11011", "10111")
names <- c("house", "car", "army", "marine", "monkey", "university", "head",
             "artist", "yellow", "blue")


df <-data.frame( id, history, names)
df  
df[grep("ar", df$names, value=T),]`

I have tried grep function as you but it doesn't work

Comment: @Ruben To get the index, you don't have to use `value=TRUE`, `df[grep("ar", df$names),]` should work.  `value=TRUE` returns the actual element. i.e. `grep("ar", df$names, value=T)
#[1] "car"    "army"   "marine" "artist"`